# Issue when web.config with build action None copied to deploy package

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, msbuild, web-config, publish

I have a legacy web api project with next project's configuration:

```
Web.config
 |- Web.Debug.config
 |- Web.Release.config 
 |- Web.Sandbox.config
 |- Web.Staging.config
```

Configuration of each `web.*.config` is - `Build Action: None; Copy to Output Directory: None;`

I created build profiles and selected proper build configuration for each. It's simple publish profiles, picture attached.[image: Sandbox publish profile]

As a test build I selected IIS single file package. Then usual, Build/Publish, select publish profile and press "Publish".

I executed test build for Sandbox environment and when I opened *.zip web deploy package I found inside next configs:

```
Web.config
Web.Release.config
Web.Sandbox.config
Web.Staging.config
```

I can't understand why it copies all web.config into deploy package, except Debug. I can't understand where is the magic there.
Also I checked my another applications and they have same settings and build doesn't contain everythings...so I'm confused and lost because I run out of all my potential solutions.